# Get the whole page content and display in the header

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Created a page and want to display all the content on the **header.php**, but it does not display anything.

code below:

```
$page = get_page_by_title( 'TEST' );
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content);
echo $content;
```

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: After `$page =`, do a `var_dump($page);die();` and see if anything appears.

Comment: nope with die(); nothing appears, if i remove die and just dump it it dumps the right stuff in the array so its getting the page, tried to get other page which is contacts and it gets the contact form but does not get other stuff in that page, the contact form is contact form 7 plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this (just replace 123 with your page ID):

```
$page_object = get_page( 123 );
$my_content=$page_object->post_content;
echo do_shortcode( $my_content );
```

Comment: thats whats returned in the div: [insert page='test' display='contents'], but nothing showing

Comment: Updated the answer to display a shortcode stored in a page.

Comment: it displays one empty div but no content: <div data-post-id="297" class="insert-page insert-page-297 "></div>

Comment: whats weird, if I get contacts page id it displays the contact form 7 but other content is not displayed.

Comment: but it only displays the athref to the page itself

Comment: I just tried it on my WordPress site and the code above seems to work. It displays the page content and runs the shortcode. Can you post a screenshot for that ahref?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149563/discussion-between-user8230352-and-z3k).

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to get:

```
$page = get_page_by_title('TEST', OBJECT, 'page');
echo $page->post_content;
```

Use following code if there is shortcode added in page and text added in the page assume Contact page:

```
$page = get_page_by_title('Contact', OBJECT, 'page');
$page->post_content;

// will match square brackets

if (preg_match('^\[(.*?)\]^', $page->post_content))
{
    echo do_shortcode($page->post_content);

}else{

    echo $page->post_content;

}
```

Use if you have text as well as shortcode in the page replace 226 with your page id;

```
$id=226;
$post = get_page($id);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
echo $content;
```

Read: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title

Comment: Just hit up arrow. Thanks @Z3K

Comment: same thing as with the above anwser from other user it displays empty, if i do with contatc page it displays '[contact-form-7 id="223" title="Contact form 1"]'

Comment: same thing for the contatcs page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149593/discussion-between-pawan-kumar-and-z3k).